# Java parameter validation, File exists, can be read and is a regular File

Tags: java, validation

I have this code to validate a `java.io.File`parameter which should not be `null`, should be accessible, should be a file and not a directory, etc.:

```
private static final String EXCEPTION_FILE_CAN_NOT_BE_READ =
    "The file %s does not seem to readable.";
private static final String EXCEPTION_PATH_DOES_NOT_EXIST =
    "The path %s does not seem to exist.";
private static final String EXCEPTION_PATH_IS_NOT_A_FILE =
    "The path %s does not seem to correspond to a file.";
private static final String EXCEPTION_PATH_REFERENCE_IS_NULL =
    "The supplied java.io.File path reference can not be null.";

public static Banana fromConfigurationFile(
    File configurationFile) {
  if (configurationFile == null) {
    String nullPointerExceptionMessage =
        String.format(EXCEPTION_PATH_REFERENCE_IS_NULL, configurationFile);
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }
  if (!configurationFile.exists()) {
    String illegalArgumentExceptionMessage =
        String.format(EXCEPTION_PATH_DOES_NOT_EXIST,
            configurationFile.getAbsolutePath());
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(illegalArgumentExceptionMessage);
  }
  if (!configurationFile.isFile()) {
    String illegalArgumentExceptionMessage =
        String.format(EXCEPTION_PATH_IS_NOT_A_FILE,
            configurationFile.getAbsolutePath());
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(illegalArgumentExceptionMessage);
  }
  if (!configurationFile.canRead()) {
    String illegalArgumentExceptionMessage =
        String.format(EXCEPTION_FILE_CAN_NOT_BE_READ,
            configurationFile.getAbsolutePath());
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(illegalArgumentExceptionMessage);
  }
  // ... more tests, like "isEncoding(X)", "isBanana(ripe)", ...
}
```

Looks like a lot of boilerplate for something I could be "pinching" from somewhere. Especially because these are not all the checks that I need, there is more (e.g. the file is a text file and has the right encoding, ...). It seems reasonable to me that there would be a simpler way to do it than this. Perhaps a FileSpecs object to construct through a Builder and to pass to a verifyFileSpecs static helper?

**Question: am I doing it wrong or is there code I could reuse?**

Answer to the FAQ for post validity:

Shows I made some research beforehand: I looked at the Java 6 SDK, that's where I got the different methods from, looked at JDK 7 and Files.isReadable, looked at Apache Commons IO, ...

Shows that this question is unique: I am specifically asking if there is code that I can reuse, I am not asking "how do I check if a path corresponds to a file and not a directory?", all of which has already an answer on SO

Why this could be useful to others: teams don't like boilerplate code like that submitted for code review, checked-in and versioned, potentially maintained (unit tests, etc.) So, borrowing the code from a reputable source would be very helpful, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would say above code is not `DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)`.

Consider using [Validate](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/Validate.html) from Apache Commons.

```
public static Banana fromConfigurationFile(File configurationFile) {
  Validate.notNull(configurationFile, String.format(EXCEPTION_PATH_REFERENCE_IS_NULL, configurationFile));
  Validate.isTrue(configurationFile.exists(), String.format(EXCEPTION_PATH_DOES_NOT_EXIST, configurationFile.getAbsolutePath()));
  Validate.isTrue(configurationFile.isFile()), String.format(EXCEPTION_PATH_IS_NOT_A_FILE, configurationFile.getAbsolutePath()));
  // and more validation...

}
```

Comment: I like it and I did not know about it. What about File-specifics though? I could not find anything in Apache Commons' FileUtils or similar packages...

Comment: i think it will not be `dry` either for `FileUtils` to have something like `FileUtils#fileExists(file, message)` and so on...

Comment: Kowser, do you think it would be a bad idea to have reusable code to check if a File exists, it is readable and a file rather than a directory, for example? How would you accomplish that yourself?

Comment: I would consider using `Validate` as first preference. Reason is, `FileUtils` is an `utility` class for `File`. Since there is `File#exists` so it is not necessary to have another method to just raise errors :)

Comment: What I meant Kowser is to have a method like verifyFile(EXISTENCE & READABILITY & FILE_NATURE) or similar.

Comment: Subclass Validate to add features you need, such as .isReadableFile().

Comment: ah, it can be done and will be good idea also if that is needed again and again for your case. Additionally that is too specific to create as a standard library.